# Create a new workbook and copy the filtered data to the workbook created

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data sheet with various project Managers names nearly 100 project managers.I want to write a VBA code to filter the data for each project manager and create a new workbook and copy the related data of the project manager to the created work book.And please make a note that the project managers names can be duplicate.

```
Sub addworksheet()

Dim wsworksheet As Worksheet
Dim nwsworksheet As Worksheet
Dim wsGMworksheet As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim NextRow As Long
Dim i As Integer

Set wsworksheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DM Names")

NextRow = wsworksheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set wsGMworksheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("GMA Data")
LastRow = wsGMworksheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With wsGMworksheet

.Range("A:AN" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:="Abani Sahoo"
.Range("A2:AN" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Copy
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
Set nwsworksheet = ActiveSheet
nwsworksheet.Range("A" & LastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
nwsworksheet.Name = wsworksheet.Range("A" & i).Value

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Please post some code that you have tried. Stackoverflow members will help you to get it working then. If you dont have any code yet, try recording - amending and then posting one.

Comment: Please find the paste link

Comment: https://bpaste.net/show/6f6fc3a8b760

Comment: And at what line do get the error

Comment: i am getting error at ".AutoFilter Field:=14,"

Comment: it is not able to filter the data

Comment: You say Project Managers name can be duplicate and then you want to apply filter on Project names, how does it identify the duplicate as two entries then?

Answer (score 0):

In the line
`.Range("A:AN" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:="Abani Sahoo"`
either **add a row number** after the first "A", i.e.
`.Range("A1:AN" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:="Abani Sahoo"`
or **loose the rows entirely**
`.Range("A:AN").AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:="Abani Sahoo"`